# How can I counterbalance a shelving cabinet with a rearward weight bias to prevent tipping?

Tags: shelving, shelf

I will add drawing soon, but I have and old stand up piano brass back with all the strings. I was going to bolt that to the back of the shelves but obviously it will make it very back heavy. I am worried that it may cause it to fall backwards, how would i counter balance this or limit the chance of it falling backwards (with out drilling into the wall)? Thanks all!

The picture is an example of what I want to do (similar). it going to be a bit bigger closer to 60h x 60w x 30d. The part with all the stings in the back will be the really heavy part. It will be directly against the wall. is there anything I should worry about with it falling backwards still. I don't want it to rely on the wall behind it.

I am turning it into a bar!

[image]

Comment: So if you don’t want to drill into the wall then it can lean against it. Or give it bigger feet.

Comment: With freestanding you mean accessible from both sides? Like a library shelf? Or close to a wall, but not against it?

Comment: Accessible from one side, and will be close to a wall. The metal piece has to weight about 100-300lbs. About 3 1/2 -4 1/2 feet tall. So when it's on that back side and how tall it is, tipping will be easy either way regardless. Would bigger feet add that much more support? Would a complete flare bottom work best?

Comment: Please show a picture and indicate the distance to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem *after* it's a problem.

Unless the weight is cantilevered *behind* the rear feet you really don't need to worry about this. The center of gravity will be inside the box, so to speak, so it would take a substantial force to tip it back. If the feet do happen to be inboard, install some that are right at the back face of the cabinet, even if they're behind the decorative ones.

I'd build the thing, then assess the issue. If necessary, mount some 1/2"x2" steel bar under the front edge as ballast, using countersunk flat-head screws and good glue.

Answer (score 0):

**Put brass back at a right angle to the end of the shelf.**

[image: schematic]

You are using salvaged piano parts to make a shelf!  Bravo!  But if it is in the back, it will be behind the books.  If you have a lot of books, people will not notice the piano piece and just see a prosaic shelf.  Boo.  Plus as you note, it is unstable.

Put the piano brass at right angles at the end of the shelf.  It should rest on the ground and in addition to its weight, will act as a wide foot to prevent tipping.  Best: it will be on full display to amaze and amuse!

And it will be accessible.  Might I suggest a pair of mallets be stored atop the piano brass.  After I finish the mead I brought to your place as a shelfwarming gift, I will play you an inspired tune.

Comment: that's actually not a bad idea to do it this way, I would have to cut it in half to use it on either side, I don't have any great metal cutting tools for something so thick. I will be stealing this mallet idea.  The piano its self was in bad condition (termite dmg) but the thing is 110 years old I couldn't let it go to waste

Comment: You do not need to cut it in half!  Just use it on one side.  I think ideals of symmetry can be set aside in the interest of art.  Eventually you may find something else that tells you it wants to be the other side.